# Is posible to load a entire file as text from resources with configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is possible to load the entire resource file as clean text with configuration with spring boot written in clean java.

This is how far I am until now:

application.yml

```
some-common-config:
   my-text-file: classpath:/<DIRECTORY>/<FILENAME>
```

Configuration class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-common-config")
public class SomeCommonConfig {
    private String myTextFile;
}
```

the file content (src/resources/test-of-file/file.txt):

```
THIS IS JUST A EXAMPLE
```

Then I want

```
assert SomeCommonConfig -> myTextFile == "THIS IS JUST A EXAMPLE"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks for asking... is important why ;)

I have some static json files, that I prefer keeping as files...
Instead of someVariable="{foo: \"boo\"} and etc

Comment: So they are not really configuration files, right? Sorry, I think I was confused to think that you want to load the properties itself as a text file.

Comment: Kind of... it is static json that doesn't change over time.

I can solve my problem by having it as clean string with the application.yml

But I really prefer to have it as having it as separate json file.
The content should just be loaded as string

Comment: There are multiple options here - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-load-resource-as-string

Comment: I have already looked that up... before writing here...
The keyword for me was InputStream as the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get it as `InputStream` and then convert the `InputStream` to whatever you like:

For example to a `String`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some-common-config")
public class SomeCommonConfig {

    private InputStream myTextFile;

    public String getText() {
        return new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(myTextFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .lines()
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }

    public InputStream getMyTextFile() {
        return myTextFile;
    }

    public void setMyTextFile(InputStream myTextFile) {
        this.myTextFile = myTextFile;
    }
}
```